# Return the number of rows expected for a group by query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I would like to get the `number of rows` returned from a mysql query that uses `group by`.
table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestRunSteps (
`idTestRunSteps` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`idUsersExecBy` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
`LastExecUserIPV4` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idTestRunSteps`);

SELECT count(*)
from proj1_db.TestRunSteps
group by idUsersExecBy,LastExecUserIPV4
```

returns

```
 3,000002,3232236222 
 1,000003,3232236222 
 5,000004,3232236222
```

What I would like to have is a simple `3` - for 3 rows. Please tell me how

Comment: That query DOES NOT return that result

Comment: Get rid of the `group by` clause.

Comment: Sorry - the query above returns 3 rows of 1 value. Select * returns what is shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of groups is the number of distinct combinations of the columns grouped by. The query that returns that number is:

```
select count(distinct idUsersExecBy, LastExecUserIPV4)
from proj1_db.TestRunSteps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from
(SELECT count(*)
from proj1_db.TestRunSteps
group by idUsersExecBy,LastExecUserIPV4) as temp
```